# Stepper motors won't move on RAMPS 1.4

Tags: marlin, ramps-1.4, motor

I have an Arduino Mega clone and RAMPS 1.4 together with A4988 drivers and NEMA 17 motors which won't move. Motors can be turned easily by hand both when the RAMPS *is* powered and is not powered. There is ~12 V between VMOT and GND on the driver. I don't have multimeter capable of detecting pulses. I have all pins under the driver connected to enable 1/16 steps. I didn't touch the pot on driver.

What I have tried:

- Using Marlin 1.x, 2.x and RAMPS 1.4 test program https://reprap.org/wiki/File:RAMPS14_test.zip which lighted up the diodes but didn't move motors.
- Different wiring (pin numbering looking on the connector on motor from the shaft side left to right)

  ```
  2B -- pin 1             2B -- pin 4
  2A -- pin 3             2A -- pin 1
  1A -- pin 4             1A -- pin 3
  1B -- pin 6             1B -- pin 6
  ```
- Tried to wire driver separately with ATX power supply following this instructable: https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/how-to-control-stepper-motor-with-a4988-driver-and-arduino/ and motors still din't run. This means I either wired it all wrong, fried all my motors or all my drivers. Is that even possible?

Can you please help me to find out what's wrong?

Comment: Please note that the default pot meter position is undefined, it is not tuned or set for use, you need to adjust it.

Comment: Thanks! I have DSO138 oscilloscope on the way so I will update the question ASAP.